# How to get the column name of the table which is Null?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

Consider following table

```
--------------------------------
ID   | ColA    | ColB   | ColC
--------------------------------
1    | ABC     |        |
2    |         | XYZ    |
3    | PQR     |        |
4    | MNO     | PQR    |
```

I need to get the first free column of the table where ID = 1. How can I do that

For example:

If `ID = 1`, next free column is `ColB`
If `ID = 2`, next free column is `ColA`
If `ID = 3`, next free column is `ColB`
If `ID = 4`, next free column is `ColC`

Comment: looks like a very weired db schema. You should consider to change the db design

Comment: @Rafael - its weird, but I have to do it. I cannot change the schema.

Comment: I cannot think of any query that mets your requirement. I guess you have to process that data by Hand

Comment: @RafaelT - You mean to say, it is not possible to fetch the column name by sql query depending on some conditions. :(

Comment: @NareshKumar - Its simple. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the name of the column you can do something like:

```
SQL> select id, cola, colb, colc,
  2         coalesce(nvl2(cola, '', 'COLA'),
                     nvl2(colb, '', 'COLB'),
                     nvl2(colc, '', 'COLC')) first_free_col
  3    from tab;

        ID COL COL COL FIRST_FREE_COL
---------- --- --- --- --------------------------------
         1 ABC         COLB
         2     XYZ     COLA
         3 PQR         COLB
         4 MNO PQR     COLC
```

or case

```
SQL> select id, cola, colb, colc,
  2         case when cola is null then 'COLA'
  3          when colb is null then 'COLB'
  4          when colc is null then 'COLC'
  5         end first_free_col
  6    from tab;

        ID COL COL COL FIRST_FREE_COL
---------- --- --- --- --------------------------------
         1 ABC         COLB
         2     XYZ     COLA
         3 PQR         COLB
         4 MNO PQR     COLC
```

Answer (score 1):

For *`sql-server`*; (if you want to consider empty string (`''`) also then use `nullif(colName,'') is null)`)

```
Select Id, case when colA is null then 'colA'
                when colB is null then 'colB'
                when colC is null then 'colC'
                ...
           end freeCol
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select case 
when ColA is not null then 'ColA'
when ColB is not null then 'ColB'
when ColC is not null then 'ColC'

End FirstCol

from test
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b999/2)

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query in mysql

```
select ID,if(colA is null,'colA',(if(colB is null,'colB',
(if(colC is null,'colC','no column is null'))))) as Result  from your_table_name
```

For your example table, if you execute my query you will get following result

[image]